# Errow when Updating mysqlDB

Tags: python, sql-update, mysql-python

Hi I have an update query that looks like this:

```
self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE files SET thumbnailPath=%s, updated_at=%s WHERE id=%s""",
                   (thumbnailPath, timestamp, fileID))
```

Where ex:

```
thumbnailPath = "/1/21/2921"
timestamp = datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 5, 12, 57, 42)
fileID = 1654
```

The error I get is this:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE id=2922' at line 1"

I don't understand where the ' comes from, can anyone help me understand whats wrong? It worked when my query didn't include the updated_at field. Another solution that could helpful is how to do an updata without affecting the updated_at field

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding quotes will resolve the problem

```
 WHERE id='%s'
```

or, since fileID is integer you can try to do the following:

```
 WHERE id=%d
```

Comment: I get this for%d :%d format: a number is required, not str and adding '%s' outputs where id='2922''

Comment: If your query worked without updated_at, double check whether value inserted into updated_at=%s is valid.

Comment: ok yea, thanks for the pointer, I realised that when I added things to updated at initially it's in string format, but not it's in datetime